# How to trigger a delayed jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, delay

I'm writing a workaround for web form. The given problem is that hitting Submit pops out a loading animation. The content is saved, but the form is still shown, as is the loading animation.

The idea is to trigger an event, 2-3 seconds after the Submit click, that will reset the form content and hide the loading animation.

How would you suggest to approach this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a read of the jQuery `delay` API: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Are you using ajax for the submit? Why not execute the code when the ajax returns?

Comment: Thanks. I'm aiming towards a "hacky" solution; I need to listen to the form somehow (as I have no access to its logic) and trigger an event once its process is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) came to the rescue.

```
$('form#id').ajaxForm(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

This will run the callback after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 3):

Use the callback functions in the events to chain them together - that way it will make sure that the action has completed, instead of trying to run all of them at the same time. If you post some code we can probably help some more. There's also the `.delay()` function, but I think callbacks are more appropriate, because your process is event driven and not time driven. You have more flexibility in the case that something in the process goes wrong, instead of statically resetting after a click.

Comment: As I have no control whatsoever on the form and its behavior, I should use the callback - where? - in the bind click event? something like $('input').click(function(), callback) ?

Comment: @konzepz it depends on what functions you're using - any chance you can post code?

Comment: Sorry, posting the code just won't do. I'm using Gravity Forms plugin for WordPress. It works nice, the only down side is that AJAX is not yet supported. That's why I'm trying to write some overriding code, to support this behavior.

Comment: @konzepz understood. You might _have_ to use `delay()` in this instance. It's definitely not preferred, though.

Answer (score 3):

Can you just use a setTimeout(...) that calls a method that resets form content and hides the animation? See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp